# PHP cURL is not working on Xampp Windows 10

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl to fetch data from different web service hosted on different location on the web. I am trying to fetch the data to my localhost.

```
    $token1="SOMETOKENXX";
    $mobileNumber= $_POST['number'];

        $postData = array(
            'mobile' =>$mobileNumber
        );
        $service_url ='http://api.hashtagloyalty.in/merchants/users/users_profile';
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $service_url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 8080);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postData));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json','Authorization:'.$token1));
        $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

//        echo($curl_response);



        if ($curl_response === false)
        {
            $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
            die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
        }else{
            echo "TRUE";
        }

        curl_close($curl);
```

I am not able to fetch the result on xampp localhost but working on GoDaddy live server.

I am working on latest version of xampp 7.2.6 and Windows 10 OS

I am accessing my localhost on port 8080 means my localhots url is localhost:8080 .

How can I know if something is blocking my request?
There is no result and giving empty result.

Please help

```
error

array ( 'url' => 'http://api.hashtagloyalty.in/merchants/users/users_profile', 'content_type' => NULL, 'http_code' => 0, 'header_size' => 0, 'request_size' => 0, 'filetime' => -1, 'ssl_verify_result' => 0, 'redirect_count' => 0, 'total_time' => 20.204, 'namelookup_time' => 1.0E-6, 'connect_time' => 0.0, 'pretransfer_time' => 0.0, 'size_upload' => 0.0, 'size_download' => 0.0, 'speed_download' => 0.0, 'speed_upload' => 0.0, 'download_content_length' => -1.0, 'upload_content_length' => -1.0, 'starttransfer_time' => 0.0, 'redirect_time' => 0.0, 'redirect_url' => '', 'primary_ip' => '', 'certinfo' => array ( ), 'primary_port' => 0, 'local_ip' => '', 'local_port' => 0, )error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info:
```

Comment: actually curl should give you some output and not just an empty result. seems a bit strange to me that there is nothing at all. anyhow: some servers dont accept requests with an empty user-agent. so, try to use a modern header like _Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17_ in the variable _CURLOPT_USERAGENT_

Comment: I am getting an error. updated the question

Comment: erm, have you used `curl_error()` to find out the actual problem yet?

Comment: I am getting this : Failed to connect to api.hashtagloyalty.in port 8080: Timed out

Comment: are you sure that the webserver that runs the api-url listens on 8080? do you have ssh access? check the open ports by _netstat -plnt_

Comment: I don't know. How to check if the api-url listen to 8080? Please help I am new to it.

Comment: as I said, @AnkitSharma, please type in _netstat -plnt_ into your shell (linux) or commandline (windows) _netstat -a_ . it will output processes and the ports they are listening on. run that command on the server that hosts the api you want to access. if there is no 8080 port open, the connection of course won't ever be established

Comment: TCP [::]:8080              ATOMCPU332:0                  LISTENING

I am getting this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curl` is not working because my organisation's proxy is blocking the request. So I have added the below code and it worked like charm :)

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxyhostandpass);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD,  $proxyusernamepass);`

Answer (score 0):

Probably a firewall issue
cURL uses port 1080 which is probably not open

Several fixes:
Open port 1080 in your firewall/router

or

Specify a (working) port for cURL
`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, PortYouWantHere)`

Comment: To see whats blocking your request, Go to your browsers' dev tools and open the networking tsb

Comment: I don't understand the network tab things. Can you help?